# Acronis True Image 2011 makes my machine run really slow?

Tags: windows-7, backup, 64-bit, acronis-trueimage

I just bought and installed Acronis True Image 2011 (I downloaded the new version using the installer). When I boot into Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit after installing it, the login runs very slowly, (I move the mouse and several seconds later the pointer moves).

When I finally do login, my CPU monitor on the desktop gadget reads 100% and I get about the same slow mouse movement.

Is there some setting I need to change? I have a 2.0GHz Dual Core Intel with 4GB of RAM.

---

Okay, I turned off the Non-Stop-Backup service and now my computer seems to run faster than it did.  Is the non-stop backup service even important, or can I just make backups when I need to instead?

Comment: (All I was really going for here was speedier backups anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non stop backup is a feature rather than a necessity, you can disable it and do manual backups.

Here is the user guide
http://download.acronis.com/pdf/ATIH2011_userguide_en-US.pdf