# Is there an expected performance regression with True Image?

Tags: windows-7, acronis-trueimage

Is there an expected notable performance regression with Acronis True Image in daily business? Daily business means, I run my computer and do **not** perform a backup right now.

At my machine TI 2014 seems to affect the system's performance. From my observations I can tell, that I sometimes see the task `TrueImageMonitor` on top of my task manager (CPU load), but it is not obviously doing something (at least not a backup).

I have disabled the True Image service as a test, the monitor is gone with no obvious difference regarding True Image's functionality. There seems to be a performance improvement on my laptop with `TrueImageMonitor` gone. So what is this monitor good for, is it safe to disable the service?

In the past there used to be something like [Non-Stop-Backup](https://superuser.com/questions/192033/acronis-true-image-2011-makes-my-machine-run-really-slow), but in Acronis TI 2014 I can not find it anymore, means I cannot disable it.

Any hints how I can my machine's performance with True Image 2014? All my backup tasks are non-scheduled but manually triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using ATI for the last 6 months and noticed no slow downs, I recommend you should reinstall True Image, and I believe that the nonstop backup feature does take up more resources than the normal backup schedule, so that might be a factor to consider, other than that, it could be just a weird issue that a reinstall should solve